# Android Service- Start service & redirect to another Activity

Tags: android, service

I want to do replication between sql server & android sqlite.That is working fine.

Once I put invoice/User click Back (my application back button) button, it need to go previous/next activity & have to start service also. I don't want to wait to go next activity.

Now the problem is : I have done this using Service. That is also fine.But when the user click back button, it wait until the service finish. after that only it go to previous/next activity.

This is my back button code:

```
 Button reOpCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reOpCancel);
    reOpCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ListRetailerActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("RetailerName", retailerName);
                bundle.putString("RetailerCode", relailerCode);
                bundle.putString("RouteCode", routeCode);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                View vi = SalesActivityGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ListRetailerActivity", i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)).getDecorView();
                SalesActivityGroup.group.replaceView(vi);

               ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(LoginActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
                boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
                if(is3g ||isWifi){
                    startService(new Intent(RetailerOptionActivity.this, UploadService.class));
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(SalesActivityGroup.group.getParent(), "GPRS/WIFI is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
           }
    });
```

This is my service code:

```
 public class UploadService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "UploadService";
private  String APPURL = "";
private  String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private  String METHOD_NAME = "convertJSONToDataSet";
private  String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IXontService/convertJSONToDataSet";
ArrayList<String> uploadFiler = new ArrayList<String>();    
HashMap<Integer,String> uploadTable = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
private String strBusinessUnit= "";
private String strExecutive = "";
private ConnectivityManager manager;
private Boolean is3g = false;
private Boolean isWifi = false;
private int networkType;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myLogedPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    strBusinessUnit = myPrefs.getString("BusinessUnit", "");
    strExecutive = myPrefs.getString("Executive", "");

    manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(DownlaodTableActivity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnected();
    isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
if (is3g) {
        APPURL =  getServicePath("G");;
    }else if (isWifi) {
        APPURL =  getServicePath("L");;
    }else if(networkType == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS) {
        APPURL =  getServicePath("G");;
    }

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Upload Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if(! APPURL.equals("")){
        boolean result = uploadUsingService();
        if(!result) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Service is not working  OR Time out to Connect to service !!!!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "GPRS/WIFI is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    onDestroy();

}

    uploadTable = getUploadTable();

    boolean result = true;

    DBAdapter dbAdapter = DBAdapter.getDBAdapterInstance(this);
    dbAdapter.openDataBase();
    System.out.println("==APPURL="+APPURL);


        try {
            if(uploadTable.size() > 0){
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : uploadTable.entrySet()) {
                    String value = entry.getValue();
                    if(value.equals("WMInvoiceHeader")){
                        result = getInvoiceHeader();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceLine")){
                        result = getInvoiceLine();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceHeaderDiscount")){
                        result = getInvoiceHeaderDiscount();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceSpecialDiscount")){
                        result = getInvoiceSpecialDiscount();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceCancelHeader")){
                        result = getInvoiceCancelHeader();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMInvoiceCancelLine")){
                        result = getInvoiceCancelLine();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMTransactionControl")){
                        result = getTransactionControl();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMVisitDetail")){
                        result = getVisitDetail();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMVisitHeader")){
                        result = getVisitHeader();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMReturnHeader")){
                        result = getReturnHeader();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMReturnLine")){
                        result = getReturnLine();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMPaymentReceipt")){
                        result = getPaymentReceipt();
                    }else if(value.equals("WMPaymentAllocation")){
                        result = getPaymentAllocation();
                    }
                    System.out.println("==result=="+result);
                    if(!result) break;
                }


        }
        dbAdapter.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("==ERROR=="+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return result;
}
```

`Problem is don't need to wait until finish service, it need to go next activity`

Please help me out from this question.

Comment: Why dont you start the service in a new thread ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not getting your issue but after reading your code I knew that your activity is not starting until the service work will have been complete is it?

In Android Service runs on UI Thread.
If you want to do some work in service better you use Thread inside the service.It will not block your UI Thread and both Thread(UI and Background) will work simultaneously.

Comment: Yes.This is my problem. Where want to write Thread ? calling place or.. Please guide me on this...

Comment: Thanks i will try this. Do you have any sample application or code ?

Comment: This suggestion too helpfully me.Working now.Without any delay.Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 agree. Also another solution can be you can use IntentService which sends broadcast to peform UI Task.